# Google Glass : return to voice_trigger / voice_prompt from the Activity

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I am new to Glass development, I have a simple application

> Ok Glass => Dictionary (voice_trigger) => Say a word to search
>   (voice_prompt) => MyActivity (app)

If I do a SWIPE_DOWN, I go back to the first view : Ok Glass. From my Activity, I would like to launch another research with a gesture, and go back to the voice_prompt view, without saying "Ok Glass" and "Dictionary".

Is it possible or do I need to avoid voice_prompt is this case ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your activity, you should be able to do something like:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Log.i(TAG, "BACK PUSHED");
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_REQUEST);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

By doing this, you stop the default handler for the swipe down and set your own, which causes the speech recognition activity to appear (https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/voice#starting_speech_recognition).

Comment: Thanks, but what I was wondering was if it was possible to return outside the app, into the voice_prompt view, waiting for the user to say a word

Comment: You'll likely have to create the intent yourself. See my edited answer.

Comment: Ok if I understand correctly, voice_prompt is more like an argument to start your Activity. I thought it was like a menu, and you could come back to it to change your choice, but no :). Thanks for you answer.